# Image does not show in browser using Web Server in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, http-headers

For the following code, if I request a html page containing an image, I cannot see the image in the browser. What am I doing wrong?

**HERE IS C# CODE:**

```
    namespace WebServer
    {
    class Program
    {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(8080);
    listener.Start();

    while (true) {

    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for connection...");
    TcpClient Client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Client.GetStream());
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Client.GetStream());

    try
    {
    string request = sr.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine(request);
    string[] tokens = request.Split(' ');
    string page = tokens[1];
    if (page == "/") {

    page = "index.htm";


    }


    StreamReader file = new StreamReader("../../web/"+page);



    sw.WriteLine("HTTP/1.0 200 ok\n");


    //send the file

    string data = file.ReadLine();

    while (data != null)
    {


    sw.WriteLine(data);
    sw.Flush();
    data = file.ReadLine();



    }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {


    //error

    sw.WriteLine("HTTP/1.0 404 ok\n");
    sw.WriteLine("<h1>Sorry! We could not find your file!</h1>");
    sw.Flush();


    }
    Client.Close();

    }




    }




    }



    }
```

Why does this problem occur, and how can I solve it?
How can i show image and video file use in browser ?